# Regexp so backslash means 'delete next char'

Tags: regex, pcre

I need a regular expression that will do the following transformation:

```
Input:  ab\xy
Output: aby


Input: ab\\xy
Output: ab\xy
```

Consider all of those backslashes as LITERAL backslashes. That is, the first input is the sequence of characters `['a', 'b', '\', 'x', 'y']`, and the second is `['a', 'b', '\', '\', 'x', 'y']`.

The rule is "in a string of characters, if a backslash is encountered, delete it and the following character ... unless the following character is a backslash, in which case delete only one of the two backslashes."

This is escape sequence hell and I can't seem to find my way out.

Comment: Could you add your programming language?

Comment: And what about `ab\\\xy`? Should it result in `ab\xy`? Or `ab\y`?

Comment: That would be `ab\y` -- the first `\\` becomes `\`, the following `\x` goes away.  It should be a PCRE.

Comment: Then it should be [`\\(\\)|\\.` replaced with `$1`](https://regex101.com/r/cShvFh/2).

Comment: @dmd Is it working as expected?

Comment: Yes! Perfect, thanks.

Comment: @dmd Ok, I posted an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
(?s)\\(\\)|\\.
```

and replace with `$1` to restore the `\` when a double backslash is found.

**Details**:

- `(?s)`  -  a dotall modifier so that `.` could match any chars inlcuding line break chars

  - `\\(\\)` - matches a backslash and then matches and captures another backslash into Group 1
- `|` - or
- `\\.` - matches any escape sequence (a backslash + any char).

See  the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/cShvFh/2) and a [PHP demo](https://ideone.com/MF4oXN):

```
$re = '/\\\\(\\\\)|\\\\./s';
$str = 'ab\\xy ab\\\\xy ab\\\\\\xy';
echo $result = preg_replace($re, '$1', $str);
// => aby ab\xy ab\y
```